# Reconstructing function from samples

Tags: sampling

Assuming I have sampled my function with frequency above nyquist frequency, using the sampling theorem I can reconstruct my original function from the sampled values.

Let's assume though that I change my original function between the sampled values, such that I keep continuity, differentiability etc..
My samples will be the same (as I didn't change the function where it is sampled), but the function will be different.
So from the sampling theorem I should recover the new function from the samples, but I should also get the original function as the sampled values the same.
How can I solve this contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sampling theorem requires that your function is bandlimited to < samplerate/2.

If it is, then there is no ambiguity in what continuous time function produced your set of samples.

Comment: ok, but even if my function is bandlimited - if I change the function values between the samples, I still get another function, while my samples are the same as for the original function. So how does the theorem hold if I can't recover the new function?

Comment: For a perfect train of modulated sinc(x) functions, there is exactly one continuous time function that can generate a given train of samples, and there is exactly one way to recreate the continuous waveform. The real world picture with finite length vectors and non-ideal filtering may be more fiddly.

Comment: @Jonathan if your function is sufficiently bandlimited, then you **cannot** change values between the samples without changing the samples. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Jonathan In other words, if you change the function between the samples, how do you guarantee that it remains bandlimited? And if by some coincidence it remains bandlimited, how do you guarantee that the maximum frequency remains the same?